# Using python-sdk on virtual pepper robot in gazebo simulator

Tags: python, pepper, gazebo-simu

I'm doing some research on navigation solutions for pepper robot and because of the current situation, I'm not able to work on a real robot so I'm using gazebo simulator.

I was trying to use exploration and mapping script that uses python-sdk but to run that script an ip address of a robot is required. I tried using ip address of my laptop and `127.0.0.1` but I get an error that it cannot connect to that address.

I also tried to change the port from `9559` to gazebo master port but it didn't help.

So my question is there any way to connect to virtual robot via ip address and if yes how can I find that ip address? I'm using packege pepper virtual and gazebo9. Thanks

Comment: Does [this document](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/pepper_moveit_config/blob/master/README.rst) help at all? Your navigation code shouldn't use the Pepper NAOQI SDK, it should instead read ROS messages (odometry, visual information, ...) and publish ROS messages (desired movements). Then you have a separate layer which interfaces the ROS commands with Pepper. This is either [pepper_gazebo_plugin](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/pepper_virtual/tree/master/pepper_gazebo_plugin) if you're using Gazebo, or [pepper_dcm_robot](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/pepper_dcm_robot) for the real robot.

Comment: Thanks for reply! So I'm am trying to compare the navigation stack I made in ROS with python-sdk script I found on github (here is a part of code from the mapping script that worries me):                                                         'Navigation = ALProxy('ALNavigation', '192.168.1.103', 11345)
Posture = ALProxy('ALRobotPosture', '192.168.1.103', 11345)
Motion = ALProxy('ALMotion', '192.168.1.103', 11345)'       I tested my nav stack in turtlebot3 simulator and it runs fine now I'm working on transfering that stack on pepper simulator and should work, but the python-sdk worries me.

Comment: [ALNavigation[(http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/alnavigation.html) provides inbuilt navigation APIs for Pepper. Do you mean you want to test your navigation stack against Pepper's inbuilt one? Unfortunately this isn't possible without a real robot. But if your navigation stack already works for the turtlebot simulator, it should work for the Pepper Gazebo simulator (maybe with some slight adjustments to topic names et c.). Run [pepper_gazebo_plugin](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/pepper_virtual/tree/master/pepper_gazebo_plugin), then run your navigation stack, no NAOqi SDK needed.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll look into it. The problem is that for ROS I already have a built map of environment as picture in png format and AlNavigation module uses explo file that you get from Exploration API and then you can get picture based map from explo file but you can't transform map picture in explo file so I need to map remap space for navigation test with AlNavigation module.

Comment: ^ apologies for the bad formatting. If you're developing your own navigation stack, you don't need the ALNavigation APIs. They're not modular in the sense that you can build on top of them. Your navigation stack will replace them. So use whichever file formats work with your code. If you're just seeking to test the performance of your navigation stack against ALNavigation - unfortunately you can't do that in simulation because ALNavigation only runs on the real robot.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help!